# Parse a text file and extract blocks of code

Tags: regex, parsing

I have this file, that contains - among other quite random things - blocks like this:

```
# MODE:
bindsym $mod+z mode "$system_mode"
mode "$system_mode" {    
    bindsym Return mode "default"
    bindsym Escape mode "default"
}

foo

# MODE:
bindsym $mod+z mode "$other_mode"
mode "$other_mode" {    
    bindsym blah blah mode "default"
    bindsym foo bar "default"
}

bar
```

And I need to extract those to another file. I tried every option in the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or/38972737#38972737) but I got as far as extracting one block:

```
sed -e '1,/# MODE:/d' -e '/}/,$d' FILE
```

returns

```
bindsym $mod+z mode "$other_mode"
mode "$other_mode" {    
    bindsym blah blah mode "default"
    bindsym foo bar "default"
```

And it is exactly what I need, but How can I get it to return *all* the blocks?

For some reason in the *real* file, the block returned is the first ; But with the above example, the block returned is the last one.

PS - I would prefer a "standard CLI tools" solution, but Perl or Python are acceptable, since they tend to be available anywhere nowadays.

Comment: "For some reason in the real file, the block returned is the first ; But with the above example, the block returned is the last one. "
 
I think for _that_ bit you might have a newline in the real file.
To "fix", you can  `sed -e '0,/# MODE:/d' -e '/}/,$d' FILE` i.e start from 0

Comment: What is the definition of your `blocks`? By which logic are the `blocks`
distinguished from other `random things`? It would be better if you can
include the random things in the example and illustrate your desired
output.

Comment: Each of those things are in the question : What a block of code *exactly* is, and there *are* "random things" in the example. Maybe read slower.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally did it in Python:

```
#!/bin/env python3

import re
import os

f = open('FILE','r')
pattern = '# MODE:\n(.*?)\}'

content = f.read()

match = re.findall(pattern,content,re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

for line in match:
    print(line)
```